# JS form validation to ensure that if a name is not entered a pop-up appears

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, user-input

The idea is that when the user is presented with the What is your name box, if they don't fill it in they would get a pop up message saying "please enter your name".

I don't understand why the form does not return the pop-up as I am calling the correct getElementsByName method I believe and checking if a value has been entered. I have tried changing the elementsByName to ("name") and ("UserInfo") but nothing happens. Does anyone have any ideas what might be the issue? I know the submit button is missing from the form but that was intentional as otherwise I'd have to post more code than necessary.

The code snippet is attached. The function name in html is called validate();

ALSO, I CANNOT MAKE ANY CHANGES TO THE HTML, IT NEEDS TO REMAIN AS IS.

```js
function Validate() {
  alert(document.getElementsByName("UserInfo")[0].value);
  if (name == "" || name == null) {
    alert('Please enter a name');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>A Simple Quiz</h2>
<fieldset>
  <legend>About You</legend>
  <p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="UserInfo" size="40" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Looks like you have case sensitivity issue, In your HTML function is `validate` with small v. But, in your JS its with capital `V'

Comment: OMG...  yeah that was the issue :'( Thank you for your keen eyes.

Comment: Does your problem got solved?

Comment: Yes thank you, it was literally the typo in Validate and I guess I didn't reference an instance of name which makes sense now as it wouldn't have been able to check for anything or even return a pop up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `name` to be empty or null but the variable `name` isn't defined hence its always executing the else part.

Below is the working model of your snippet.
I had assigned the input value to `value` and check for existence, do alert if not a valid input.

```js
function Validate(){
  const value = document.getElementsByName("UserInfo")[0].value;

  if(!value) {
    alert('Please enter a name');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>A Simple Quiz</h2>
<form onsubmit="Validate()">
<fieldset>
 <legend>About You</legend>
    <p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="UserInfo" size="40" required />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**
Use `required` attribute.

Even better approach would be to wrap all the elements and submit button inside form and add `required` attribute to all required elements. Updated the answer.

Adding required will abort the submit itself.

Comment: Please note that the notation !value will work with "", undefined and null.

Comment: It still doesn't run and I am wondering if it is because there are another three elements that need to be tested before the whole form can be submitted? It just takes the page to the processing html.

Comment: @schankam Ah, I missed it. Thanks for noticing. Also, I updated the answer to use `required` attribute.

Comment: @JessicaGraham I suppose adding the required attribute will make sure all the values are available before submitting. Once values are entered and hit submit you can perform additional checks like min character length of the name, password strength, etc and show alerts/errors accordingly. Please check my updated answer.